# How to search my database by using an array of words?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, arrays, stored-procedures

I'm attempting to setup a search function from a string a user types. (ex: "John Doe" or "Doe, John")
I was thinking I would use `Replace(SearchString, ",", "")` to get rid of the commas the user might enter, and then use `Split(SearchString, " ")` to get all the words into an array.  Once they're in the array I would execute a Stored Procedure on each of the terms and build a DataTable with the results.

Below is what I'm wanting to use for executing my stored procedure.

```
oCommand = DataAccess.GetSQLCommand("MyStoredProcedure", CommandType.StoredProcedure, SourceServer.ConnectionLocal)
oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MySearchString", SearchString)

oAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(oCommand)

oAdapter.Fill(MyDataTable)
```

Now I'm thinking the "SearchString" I will assign while looping through my array of words... but this doesn't seem like the right way to do this. Maybe it is but I don't know how to append my next result to the previous DataTable either.

Comment: It might be useful to mention whether you are working with a specific database engine or not. For example, SQL Server offers a FullText capability that, if available, would allow you to offload most of the work to the database in a case like this

Comment: @Tarwn sorry using SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some great ideas for using arrays and Lists in SQL Server on this page - http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html

I personally find the XML method the most useful;
http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#XML

An example of how I've used this in the past is;

```
 DECLARE @indata nvarchar(max)
 DECLARE @hDoc int
 SET @indata = '
    <ROOT>
        <SearchTerm code="Test search term"></SearchTerm>
        <SearchTerm code="Other search term"></SearchTerm>
        <SearchTerm code="Next search term"></SearchTerm>
    </ROOT>'

 CREATE TABLE #searchTerm (
    code varchar(40)
 )   

 EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @indata

 INSERT Into #searchTerm
 SELECT code
 FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/ROOT/SearchTerm',1) 
     WITH (code varchar(50))

 EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc    

 -- Use the data in #searchTerm as needed in your query
 SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE searchValue IN (SELECT code FROM #searchTerm) 

 DROP TABLE #searchTerm
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing in the comma separated values in as a single string of nvarchar. Then use the SELECT FROM WHERE IN structure within your stored procedure. Create the sql command wwithin your stored procedure by concatenation and then call EXEC @sql

```
Declare @sql = 

'SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE person IN(' + @Application + ')'

exec(@sql)
```

Beware, if your list of search criteria is large this may not be the best solution for you.

Note that the commas should be between the full names not the first name and last name.

Comment: That seems to be a clever solution considering I was trying to remove the commas! haha. I'll try this and see what I come up with thanks! I'll post back with my results.

Comment: Is it possible to use wildcards with the words/names while in the IN statement?